# magento price cart rule -> quantity greater than product attribute value

Tags: php, magento, conditional-statements

I'm not sure how to solve the following magento price cart rule problem.

I would like to give 5% extra discount for each item in cart where the purchased quantity is greater than the value of attribute "big_box" for that item. 
(In short if a customer orders full box of one item he gets 5% extra discount.)

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
    Quantity in cart  equals or greater than 48
```

I have created a rule that does that but since I have >5000 configurable items and they have vastly different values of big_box attribute, it's impractical to create a separate rule for each item.

I would like to modify the upper example so that instead of fixed value "48" i can enter attribute name "big_box".
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin and open your attribute.

There is an option called;

```
Use for Promo Rule Conditions
```

Set this to 'yes'.  You can now use it as a condition in your basket rule.

Comment: I know for that option but it doesn't help in may case since I would like to modify the last line of the rule to:

    Quantity in cart  equals or greater than big_box